# default Value in the Ember 1.0.0-RC.1 and Ember Data Revision 11

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the latest emberjs release, how to define default value for DS.attr ?

`attributeName: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false })`

The above no longer works

Comment: It *does* work for me. Are there any special circumstances around the creation, property name, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The latest ember-data is returning empty model attributes as null. The code only checks for undefined with

```
if (value === undefined) {
  value = options.defaultValue;
}
```

You could throw a quick fix in around line number 3929 (of latest compiled from source) with:

```
if (value === undefined || value === null) {
  value = options.defaultValue;
}
```

and it will work. I will try to send a pull request, but not sure if this is the correct fix.